# How to open Excel 2010 as separate files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do I open multiple Excel 2010 workbooks as separate files.  I do not want to have to toggle between the two or more I want to use on split screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in windows 7, then right click on the windows icon on your taskbar and the 3rd item from the bottom will say Microsoft Excel 2010. Click that and it will open a new instance of Excel in a new window.
(I think that in other windows versions, you just need to find the Excel .exe file and open that rather than opening up your .xlsx files directly... I think)

Just a minor thing about doing this, you can't copy and paste cells as formulae across instances and you can move a worksheet across instances.